What is the best way to separate docker base image and development image?
In our complex project we have a docker image that is used for development and for CI, and it's almost identical to the production image. The problem is that building the image is a very long process, that takes up to 45 minutes.
We start from a standard debian base, then install a lot of stuff, and we have to compile a sizable amount of software dependencies in this process. As a result, the CI takes a long time just to set up the environment, and we have the same problem while developing locally for some caching issues docker seems to have (when the cache works properly this problem is very well mitigated).
Since the most part of these dependencies change very rarely (things like programming language versions), an option would be to define a base image with this stuff, tag it using a hash of the files defining these dependencies, and push it to an internal registry. Then, the rest of the image would start from there and would be ready in a very short time.
We would like to implement something like this, in a way that once the repository has been checked out, a simple docker compose run -it dev bash (where dev is the name of the development docker image) would do the trick. By "do the trick" I mean:

Check the hash of the basic dependencies files
Pull the corresponding base image from the registry.
If that is missing, build it and tag it locally.
Build the development image on top of the base one.
Start a shell inside the development image.

The continuous integration system would add "Push the new base image to the registry" as point 3.1.
Is there a flaw with this idea?
Is this even possible to implement such that it becomes that simple to use?
What is the best way to do it?

The concept of building a base image with dependencies preinstalled is sound.  Is there a specific problem you're running into?  I tend to be a little dubious of setups that hide developer tools inside containers, and your initial description of building one image for CI and then pushing a different untested image to production often isn't a recommended approach.

It's a long story... We have some slight differences that we would like to get rid of, possibly employing a better containerization design like the one I'm proposing. The current situation is inconvenient, but not dangerous, because the production image is thoroughly tested as well. There is some duplication we'd like to address.

I found your question interesting. Can you do this without setting up a registry to host your built Docker Images? I'm just wondering how much work it would be to build an internal server to host these images, especially since once the image is built you don't need to continually rebuild and cache it somewhere. Can you build the second Image, based on the first, where the first Image is just a local file somewhere? (I'm assuming here you don't want to push your images to a public resource like Docker Hub.)

@user2138149 docker registries are a very convenient way to store images, both locally and globally. Some services like GitHub offer to store images privately to an organization. Docker commands will look for images in the configured registries, if they don't find them locally and they are tagged correctly. So I think that using a registry is a convenient tool for this task.

@Spiros I see - so you already have a private hosting solution for this? Hence using that is easier than managing some local files.
